# ADOdb check if table exists PHP

Tags: php, sql, adodb

How to check a table exists in PHP ADOdb, for an independed/unkown DB-System?

There are several solutions arround, specific to some DB-system, but I need a solution working on PHP ADOdb.

By using ADOdb I can't rely on the INFORMATION.SCHEMA and the like, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db' 
 AND table_name = 'tablename'
LIMIT 1;
```

because they are all DB-specific, and error causing queries are also not applicable, like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM 'testtable' LIMIT 1;
```

because this would cause, at least in my case, a silent error, but I can't predict the behavior on other DB-systems.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some hours to find a working solution. Here `$oADOdbCon` is a initialized a "ready to use" connection to some database.

```
$rs = $oADOdbCon->execute("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tablename';");

if ($rs->RecordCount() == 1) {
   // do something
}
```

In some cases it will come handy to check the availability of a set of tables at once, or perhaps a somewhat extended `SHOW TABLES` functionallity check, here the wildcard operator `%` comes handy, so the same query from above could be rephrased to:

```
$rs = $oADOdbCon->execute("SHOW TABLES LIKE '%tablename%';");
```

In this case not only the table 'tablename' is found but also all it's name siblings like 'a_tablename' or 'some_tablename_s'. And therefore the checking has take into account the possibility of multiple results:

```
if ($rs->RecordCount() >= 1) {
   // do something
}
```

ANd to show the tables found:

```
while (!$rs->EOF) {
     print $rs->fields[0] . '<BR>';
     $rs->MoveNext();
}
```